# ScrollView navigationlink still active across VStack and GeometryReader, XCode12, beta 4

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Using XCode12, beta 4, I am trying to separate a header area and a ScrollView. I've tried both VStack and GeometryReader; however, when I click in the header area, the navigation link in the ScrollView item beneath it is triggered.

If I use a list, this undesired behavior is not observed. If I use the ScrollView in XCode 11.6 and build for iOS13, this undesired behavior is also not observed.

Did something change with ScrollViews in VStacks or GeometryReaders in iOS14?  Why does the scrollview "slide" under the object in the VStack or GeometryReader?

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
   NavigationView{
    //GeometryReader { geo in
     VStack{
      VStack{
       Text("Blah")
      }//.frame(height: geo.size.height*0.20)
      
      VStack {
       ScrollView {
        ForEach(0..<10) { i in
         NavigationLink(destination: Text("\(i)")) {
          cardRow(i: i)
           .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
           .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
           .padding()
           .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
           .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemFill))
           .padding()
         }
        }
       }
      }//.frame(height: geo.size.height*0.90)
      
    }
   }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
  }
    
  struct cardRow: View {
   var i: Int
    
   var body: some View {
    HStack {
     VStack {
      Text("88")
     }.hidden()
     .overlay(
      VStack{
       Text("\(i)")
      }
     )
     Divider()
      .background(Color(UIColor.label))
     Spacer()
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is worked solution (tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14)

```
  VStack {
   ScrollView {
    ForEach(0..<10) { i in
     NavigationLink(destination: Text("\(i)")) {
      cardRow(i: i)
       .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
       .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
       .padding()
       .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
       .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemFill))
       .padding()
     }
    }
   }.clipped().contentShape(Rectangle())    // << here !!
  }
```

Comment: Thanks!  But why do we need to clip the ScrollView now?  What changed or is it a bug...it seems counterintuitive that we have to worry about overlaps and interactions between a ScrollView and other items in the stack.